# .NET dataadapter returns duplicate records when actual SQL returns as expected

Tags: .net, datagridview, duplicates, dataadapter

Populating a datagridview sourced from the DataAdapter, I get duplicate records -- there aren't actually duplicate records in the database (SQL Server 2008).   When I run the same SQL in SSMS query window results are normal (no duplicates).  I'm using a "select distinct" statement (no outer-joins)

Are there any settings that would prevent duplicate records in the dataadapter?  I don't want to remove duplicates manually (as I've seen in some discussions, that's just wrong).  It's straight forward, nothing is returned from the db that's duplicate, yet somehow they're showing up.  I can't even duplicate this in a development env, it occurs only in 1 specific running instance of the application.

Comment: Is there any client sude caching going on; snything distinct about the client in question? Different browser, anything along those lines?

Comment: No, it's an application not running in browser.  I just rebooted that particular server to make sure this is not a memory issue... as I mentioned , I think the "distinct" feature is being ignored for some reason...

Comment: Maybe code of how you populate datagridview with DataAdapter will help?  Ffrom MSDN Method `DataAdapter.Fill` - "_Adds or refreshes rows in the DataTable_"